# Is there a way to extract the most current values when comparing multiple date columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

The question might be confusing but what I am trying to do is to extract the color from the most recent two years and also identify the year.

For example, I have a dataset below, for item1, the color for the most recent two years are red (2021) and black(2020), the desired outcome is to add 4 columns namely "this year color", "last year color", "this year", "last year" to show the corresponding information.

In the case of current year's color (2021) is missing, then the logic is to take the next year as current year, like item 3, this year's color is green (2020) and last year color is green (2018).

I wonder if there is a way to do it in python? Any advice or suggestion would be gladly appericated.

```
import pandas as pd 

df1 = { 'item':['item1','item2','item3','item4'],
  '2018':['red','green','',''],
  '2019':['black','','green','red'],
  '2020':['brown', 'blue','','blue'],
  '2021':['','','green','black']}

df1=pd.DataFrame(df1)
df1
```

The desired output is like below:

[image]

Comment: Where are you getting `this year` and `last year`?

Comment: I am trying to get "this year" and "last year" based on the information I have for df1. For example, if there is color (or color is not missing) in 2021, then "this year" is 2021

Comment: The df1 in the question doesn't match the left hand side of expected output - the dates are reversed. Would you mind corrected the question, please? It will make the desired output clearer, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC, you can use a custom function:

```
def getlast(s):
    s = s[s.ne('')][:2]
    return pd.Series(s.to_list()+s.index.to_list(),
                     index=['this year color', 'last year color', 'this year', 'last year'])
df2 = df1.join(df1
 .drop('item', axis=1)
 .sort_index(axis=1, ascending=False)
 .apply(getlast, axis=1)
)
```

output:

```
    item   2018   2019   2020   2021 this year color last year color this year last year
0  item1    red  black  brown                  brown           black      2020      2019
1  item2  green          blue                   blue           green      2020      2018
2  item3         green         green           green           green      2021      2019
3  item4           red   blue  black           black            blue      2021      2020
```

or using `melt` and `merge`:

```
df2 = df1.merge(df1
 .melt(id_vars='item')
 .loc[lambda d: d['value'].ne('')]
 .groupby('item')
 .agg(**{'this year color': ('value', lambda g: g.iloc[-1]),
       'last year color': ('value', lambda g: g.iloc[-2]),
       'this year': ('variable', lambda g: g.iloc[-1]),
       'last year': ('variable', lambda g: g.iloc[-2])}),
 left_on='item', right_index=True
)
```

Comment: Thanks mozway, I have a question. In my real dataset, those empty value are not '', instead they are showing as NaN, how should I modify the '' from s.ne('') to NaN?

Comment: If real `NaN`, use `d['value'].notna()` or replace the whole `loc` line by `dropna(subset='value')`

Comment: @user032020 it is `notna` not `isna`, sorry

Comment: thanks mozway. sometime I got confuse between pandas and python when identifying null. For example, pd.isnull() works for pandas, but when I use if then else logic in a function like if x.isnull(): it will give me an error